# How can I rotate tables in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Hi I want to rotate a table on Microsoft word so that I can print it off on an A5 sheet. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your question but a solution that doesn't require you to tilt your head to edit your table in word: Do not rotate the table itself but the layout of the page that it is on. Use a sections break (`Insert --> Break --> Section break`) before and after the table to keep the other pages in portrait layout.